# Storing PendingIntents in SQLite or using other means?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I'm trying to log all incoming notifications to show a history of it in my app.

I've managed to store details such as title, text, etc this way, but how would I go about storing the pendingIntent of each notification?

I can't do this in SQLite AFAIK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but how would I go about storing the pendingIntent of each notification?

You don't. A `PendingIntent` exists solely in memory. You have no getter methods of significance to pull data out of a `PendingIntent`. And, part of what it contains — information about the app that created the `PendingIntent` — you have no means of reproducing.

If these were *your* `PendingIntents`, you could save the information you used to create them in the first place. But, they are `PendingIntents` created by other apps, and so they cannot be persisted in any meaningful way.